# Can we upload the file to server from iPhone app other than photo, video and audio

Tags: iphone, ios6

I have the option in my app to share the file. I have to upload the any file from iPhone to server. Is it possible, as far i know iPhone gallery only shows videos and images from where i can upload the file then, what user can browse to upload file. I have no idea about the thing i am talking. Please guide. Thanks in advance.

Comment: YES, you can upload the any kind of files to server.you have to just tell to server what kind of extension of file you are sending.

Comment: @Sachin But what to open for browsing the file, here user need to pick the file from iPhone from where i can do that?

Answer (score 0):

For that you can use `iCloud` concept. With `iCloud` you can upload, download any type of file other then picture, video, audio file. But i am not sure that you can see it in any type of browsing media or in document directory. As per my knowledge you have to make custom UI for that

You can check detailed document on iCloud [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/Introduction.html)

Comment: That is the main issue i am having browsing media. But i didn't got how to create custom UI for that.